# How to ignore trigger() method first time my page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 dropdowns. 1st dropdown is a static one. Based on the first dropdown I am populating second dropdown. Based on a 2nd dropdown I am populating 3rd one. 2nd and 3rd dropdown are dynamic. I am getting from backend.

I am using triger() method to retain my dropdown after page refresh. Now problem is at the time of page loading itself my rest call is happening for 2nd and 3rd dropdowns also.

Now I want to ignore trigger() for the first time my page is loading.

This is my code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#customerDetails").change(function() {
            var value1 = $('#customerDetails :selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'environments',
                data : {
                    selectedcustomername : value1
                },
                success : function(result) {
                    getEnvNames(result);
               }
            });
        }).trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you expect a serious answer if you don't even take the presentation of your own question seriously?

Comment: @jyothi Exactly!!!..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `.trigger('change')` at the end of your code which triggers onChange event when page loads. Just remove that code and that should solve your problem.